# Create a sum of acolumn that increases with each row

Tags: r

Hey guys this one might be kind of easy to answer, but I haven't found any solution yet.
I have the following data frame.

```
 obj <- data.frame (
      yr = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995),
      occ = c(223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228))
```

my goal is now to create another variable that is sums up the `occ` variable, but in an ongoing way.

```
occ occsum
223  223
224  446
225  671
226  797
227  1024
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps `cumsum(occ)`

Comment: Shouldn't your second entry be 447?  And then the rest are off as well.